# jQuery .show/.hide Using

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I try .show and auto hide other showing div. But i cant run it.

Here my code example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Awersione/PR7ag/

.

I Try Some examples But Dont Work My Code.
I Need Some Help..

Thanks For All Help

Comment: You might want to un-indent your link, so it will appear as a clickable link

Comment: you have not selected jquery in the fiddle

Comment: The jsFiddle example seems to work for me if I select jQuery 1.7.1 from the framework drop down (if you click on that link it loads with Mootools 1.4.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you select jQuery as your framework on the left and you're good to go! 
http://jsfiddle.net/PR7ag/2/

EDIT

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PR7ag/12/) what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to enable jQuery on your jsfiddle
2. Use .toggleClass, see http://jsfiddle.net/number5/PR7ag/6/

Answer (score 0):

I fix your fsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PR7ag/4/

Few pointers:

1. On the left panel you had mootool selected as your framework, not jQuery
2. In the selector use `>` to select the child